# Передача POST/GET

Tags: php, ajax

Загружаю контент на страницу таким образом:

```
// Вытаскиваем конфиг в ассоциативный массив
$jsonString = file_get_contents(__DIR__ . '/data/config.json');
$config = json_decode($jsonString, true);

// Определяем текущую страницу
$page = trim($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/');

// Если $page == '', то есть REQUEST_URI = '/', то эта страница главная
if ($page == '') {
    $page = $config['mainPage'];
}

// Заголовок сайта
$siteTitle = $config['siteTitle'];

// Если страница не существует, возвращаем 404 Not Found
if (!isset($config['pages'][$page])) {
    // Отдаем код 404
    header('HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found');

    // Подключаем шаблон 404 страницы
    include_once __DIR__ . '/templates/404.php';
    die;
}

// Заголовок и меню страницы
$pageData = $config['pages'][$page];
$pageTitle = $pageData['title'];
$pageMenu = $pageData['menu'];

// Содержимое страницы
$content = file_get_contents(__DIR__ . '/templates/' . $page . '.php');

// Подключаем шаблон главной страницы
include_once __DIR__ . '/templates/index.php';
```

Для перехода между страницами использую:

```
<a href="main" data-menu="main" data-link="ajax" <?php echo ($pageMenu == 'main') ? ' class="active"' : '' ?> class="sl-menu-link"></a>
```

Каким образом можно передать на загружаемую часть страницы POST/GET запрос в данном случае?

Comment: Не могли бы Вы уточнить, какой именно фреймворк/библиотека обрабатывает у Вас эти `data-` атрибуты? Это какой-нибудь wordpress плагин?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

На этой самой странице, вам нужно делать Ajax запрос на сервер, передавая числовое ID страницы, на сервере в свою очередь, вы отдаёте этому ID нужный вам контент. Такой можно провернуть и с самой первой главной страницей, чтобы запрос был именно через Ajax.

Comment: А если допустим мне нужно получить запрос вида site.ru/main123 где 123 -  данные?

Comment: Тогда вы просто передаете такой параметр при Ajax запросе а на сервере получаете его соотвественно в массиве данных. Ну или же вы можете Ajax запросом сразу послать его таким примерно образом `main123` Ну а на сервере распарсить данные.

Comment: Не забудьте если вас устраивает ответ поставить соответющую галку, это поможет соорентирваться тем кто будет разбираться в этом вопросе дальше.